# Bootstrap Date picker set date two input box start to end and disable dynamic date value if select drop down change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used Bootstrap Date picker in my project.
Set two input box from start date to end date.
Start date is select after today and end date is after starting date.
get data base thought array(dynamic) to set disable date in date picker.
when select drop down change event get different different(dynamic) date value disable.

```
    function setbookdate(id) {
         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: Admin_url + 'invoice/bookeddate/'+id,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(response) {
                var data =  jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                var booked = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, input) {
                    booked.push(input);
                });
                $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        autoclose:true,
                        format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
                        todayHighlight: true,
                        todayBtn: "linked", 
                        startDate: '0', 
                        datesDisabled: booked
                    });
                    $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
                });
            }            
        });
    }


    $("#pickup_date, #return_date").on('change', function(a){
        var start = $("#pickup_date").datepicker('getDate');  
        var end = $("#return_date").datepicker('getDate');  
        if(start>end){
            $( "#return_date" ).datepicker('setDate',new Date(start));
        }
    });
```

my issues is date formate change in second date picker.
second issues is dynamic value select and set only one time means i have select drop down and return 3 value of date e.g 1,2,3,jan after change dropdown get date is 8,9,10 jan. first time set disable 1,2,3 date but after change not set in 8,9,10 jan disable.

Please any one responses me.

Comment: You're using wrong translator I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#product').on('change', function(){
        var pid =  $("#product").val().split('-_-'); 
        var id = pid[0];
        setbookdate(id);
    });



    function setbookdate(id, in_id = '', pickupdate = '', returndate = '') {
        var info = {'id': id , 'in_id':in_id};
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: Admin_url + 'invoice/bookeddate',
            data: info,

            success: function(response) {

                var data =  jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                var booked = [];

                $('#datepiker_pickup_retuen').html('');
                var html = "<label class='control-label'>Pickup Date<span class='rerq'>*</span></label>";
                var html1 = '<div class="input-group input-daterange"><input type="text" name="pickup_date" placeholder="Pickup Date" id="pickup_date" readonly="" class="pickup_date form-control"><div class="input-group-addon">to</div><input type="text" name="return_date" placeholder="Return Date" id="return_date" readonly="" class="return_date form-control"></div>'; 
                $('#datepiker_pickup_retuen').html(html+html1);

                $.each(data, function (key, input) {
                    booked.push(input);
                });

                if(in_id != ''){
                    $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
                        $(this).datepicker({
                            autoclose:true,
                            format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
                            todayHighlight: true,
                            todayBtn: 'linked', 
                            datesDisabled: booked
                        });

                        $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.input-daterange input').each(function() {
                        $(this).datepicker({
                            autoclose:true,
                            format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
                            todayHighlight: true,
                            todayBtn: 'linked', 
                            startDate: '0', 
                            datesDisabled: booked
                        });

                        $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
                    });
                }
                $('#pickup_date').datepicker('setDate', pickupdate);
                $('#return_date').datepicker('setDate', returndate);
            }            
        });
    }

    $(document).on('change', '#pickup_date', function() {
         $("#return_date").val('');   
    });

    $(document).on('change', '#return_date', function() {
        var pick = $("#pickup_date").datepicker('getDate');
        var ret = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if(pick<=ret){}  
        else {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', pick);
        }
    });
```